# The LinkedIn videos API returns internal server error when uploading videos with size of about 7mb and above

Tags: linkedin-api

When I try uploading a video with size 7mb, an internal server error is returned. However, short video(size <= 1mb) are uploaded successfully.

Upload request

```
 foreach ($mediaUrl as $url) {
                    $fileStr = str_replace(base_url(), APPPATH . '../', $file);
                    $cmd = 'curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --upload-file  ' . $fileStr . ' "' . $url->uploadUrl . '"';
                    exec($cmd . " 2>&1", $response);
                    logg_message(to_json($response), 'video_response');
                }
```

Response

```
"  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current",
    "                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed",
    "\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 13.107.42.14:443...",
    "* Connected to www.linkedin.com (13.107.42.14) port 443 (#0)",
    "* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate",
    "* ALPN: offers http/1.1",
    "* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1",
    "> PUT /dms-uploads/C4D10AQHZMQoE4Z9Vfw/uploadedVideo?sau=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%253D&pn=1&m=527741031&app=123523604&sync=0&v=beta&ut=2eCCIxaTzwwGE1 HTTP/1.1",
    "> Host: www.linkedin.com",
    "> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1",
    "> Accept: */*",
    "> Content-Type:application/octet-stream",
    "> Content-Length: 7644024",
    "> Expect: 100-continue",
    ">",
    "* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse",
    "< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue",
    "\r  0 7464k    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0} [16384 bytes data]",
    "\r  1 7464k    0     0    1  128k      0  74203  0:01:43  0:00:01  0:01:42 74219\r  3 7464k    0     0    3  224k      0  82118  0:01:33  0:00:02  0:01:31 82125\r  4 7464k    0     0    4  336k      0  89417  0:01:25  0:00:03  0:01:22 89413\r  6 7464k    0     0    6  448k      0  95409  0:01:20  0:00:04  0:01:16 95414\r  7 7464k    0     0    7  560k      0  99389  0:01:16  0:00:05  0:01:11  111k\r  9 7464k    0     0    9  672k      0    98k  0:01:15  0:00:06  0:01:09  108k\r 10 7464k    0     0   10  768k      0  95005  0:01:20  0:00:08  0:01:12   99k\r 11 7464k    0     0   11  864k      0    98k  0:01:16  0:00:08  0:01:08  106k\r 12 7464k    0     0   12  960k      0  97160  0:01:18  0:00:10  0:01:08 98754\r 13 7464k    0     0   13  992k      0  94430  0:01:20  0:00:10  0:01:10 88686\r 14 7464k    0     0   14 1104k      0  94954  0:01:20  0:00:11  0:01:09 86552\r 15 7464k    0     0   15 1184k      0  94076  0:01:21  0:00:12  0:01:09 92404\r 16 7464k    0     0   16 1264k      0  93831  0:01:21  0:00:13  0:01:08 82133\r 18 7464k    0     0   18 1360k      0  93682  0:01:21  0:00:14  0:01:07 86267\r 19 7464k    0     0   19 1440k      0  93396  0:01:21  0:00:15  0:01:06 91203\r 20 7464k    0     0   20 1536k      0  93576  0:01:21  0:00:16  0:01:05 90223\r 21 7464k    0     0   21 1616k      0  92295  0:01:22  0:00:17  0:01:05 87754\r 22 7464k    0     0   22 1712k      0  92175  0:01:22  0:00:19  0:01:03 87816\r 24 7464k    0     0   24 1808k      0  93604  0:01:21  0:00:19  0:01:02 93356\r 25 7464k    0     0   25 1904k      0  93353  0:01:21  0:00:20  0:01:01 93237\r 26 7464k    0     0   26 1984k      0  93250  0:01:21  0:00:21  0:01:00 92137\r 27 7464k    0     0   27 2048k      0  91308  0:01:23  0:00:22  0:01:01 87806\r 28 7464k    0     0   28 2144k      0  92245  0:01:22  0:00:23  0:00:59 92506\r 29 7464k    0     0   29 2192k      0  90563  0:01:24  0:00:24  0:01:00 78564\r 30 7464k    0     0   30 2272k      0  90226  0:01:24  0:00:25  0:00:59 76888\r 31 7464k    0     0   31 2336k      0  89408  0:01:25  0:00:26  0:00:59 72553\r 32 7464k    0     0   32 2416k      0  88834  0:01:26  0:00:27  0:00:59 77188\r 33 7464k    0     0   33 2480k      0  88408  0:01:26  0:00:28  0:00:58 69860\r 34 7464k    0     0   34 2576k      0  87039  0:01:27  0:00:30  0:00:57 71221\r 35 7464k    0     0   35 2656k      0  88261  0:01:26  0:00:30  0:00:56 78189\r 37 7464k    0     0   37 2768k      0  88857  0:01:26  0:00:31  0:00:55 85996\r 38 7464k    0     0   38 2848k      0  88761  0:01:26  0:00:32  0:00:54 88367\r 39 7464k    0     0   39 2928k      0  88863  0:01:26  0:00:33  0:00:53 91475\r 40 7464k    0     0   40 3008k      0  88493  0:01:26  0:00:34  0:00:52 98282\r 41 7464k    0     0   41 3104k      0  88774  0:01:26  0:00:35  0:00:51 91934\r 43 7464k    0     0   43 3216k      0  89593  0:01:25  0:00:36  0:00:49 94412\r 43 7464k    0     0   43 3280k      0  88341  0:01:26  0:00:38  0:00:48 85680\r 45 7464k    0     0   45 3360k      0  88641  0:01:26  0:00:38  0:00:48 87183\r 45 7464k    0     0   45 3408k      0  87279  0:01:27  0:00:39  0:00:48 79119\r 46 7464k    0     0   46 3488k      0  87480  0:01:27  0:00:40  0:00:47 78267\r 47 7464k    0     0   47 3536k      0  86175  0:01:28  0:00:42  0:00:46 62296\r 48 7464k    0     0   48 3616k      0  86588  0:01:28  0:00:42  0:00:46 72526\r 49 7464k    0     0   49 3696k      0  86099  0:01:28  0:00:43  0:00:45 66912\r 50 7464k    0     0   50 3760k      0  85726  0:01:29  0:00:44  0:00:45 73113\r 51 7464k    0     0   51 3824k      0  85519  0:01:29  0:00:45  0:00:44 69367\r 51 7464k    0     0   51 3872k      0  84695  0:01:30  0:00:46  0:00:44 71724\r 53 7464k    0     0   53 3984k      0  85404  0:01:29  0:00:47  0:00:42 75291\r 54 7464k    0     0   54 4064k      0  85405  0:01:29  0:00:48  0:00:41 79000\r 55 7464k    0     0   55 4160k      0  85341  0:01:29  0:00:49  0:00:40 81887\r 56 7464k    0     0   56 4240k      0  85319  0:01:29  0:00:50  0:00:39 83526\r 57 7464k    0     0   57 4320k      0  85455  0:01:29  0:00:51  0:00:38 92639\r 59 7464k    0     0   59 4416k      0  84980  0:01:29  0:00:53  0:00:36 81257\r 60 7464k    0     0   60 4496k      0  84901  0:01:30  0:00:54  0:00:36 80445\r 61 7464k    0     0   61 4576k      0  85563  0:01:29  0:00:54  0:00:35 87849\r 62 7464k    0     0   62 4672k      0  85699  0:01:29  0:00:55  0:00:34 89620\r 63 7464k    0     0   63 4768k      0  85848  0:01:29  0:00:56  0:00:33 89845\r 64 7464k    0     0   64 4816k      0  85074  0:01:29  0:00:57  0:00:32 86122\r 65 7464k    0     0   65 4912k      0  85416  0:01:29  0:00:58  0:00:31 91393\r 66 7464k    0     0   66 4992k      0  85488  0:01:29  0:00:59  0:00:30 84671\r 67 7464k    0     0   67 5056k      0  85231  0:01:29  0:01:00  0:00:29 79905\r 68 7464k    0     0   68 5120k      0  84615  0:01:30  0:01:01  0:00:29 70856\r 69 7464k    0     0   69 5200k      0  84879  0:01:30  0:01:02  0:00:28 82504\r 70 7464k    0     0   70 5296k      0  85084  0:01:29  0:01:03  0:00:26 81042\r 72 7464k    0     0   72 5392k      0  85288  0:01:29  0:01:04  0:00:25 82864\r 73 7464k    0     0   73 5488k      0  85439  0:01:29  0:01:05  0:00:24 87963\r 74 7464k    0     0   74 5584k      0  85584  0:01:29  0:01:06  0:00:23 97945\r 75 7464k    0     0   75 5632k      0  84796  0:01:30  0:01:08  0:00:22 83813\r 76 7464k    0     0   76 5696k      0  84725  0:01:30  0:01:08  0:00:22 80250\r 77 7464k    0     0   77 5776k      0  84802  0:01:30  0:01:09  0:00:21 78533\r 78 7464k    0     0   78 5840k      0  84481  0:01:30  0:01:10  0:00:20 71916\r 78 7464k    0     0   78 5872k      0  83708  0:01:31  0:01:11  0:00:20 58747\r 79 7464k    0     0   79 5968k      0  83994  0:01:31  0:01:12  0:00:19 72480\r 81 7464k    0     0   81 6064k      0  84086  0:01:30  0:01:13  0:00:17 75306\r 82 7464k    0     0   82 6160k      0  84394  0:01:30  0:01:14  0:00:16 78674\r 84 7464k    0     0   84 6272k      0  84677  0:01:30  0:01:15  0:00:15 87441\r 85 7464k    0     0   85 6368k      0  84831  0:01:30  0:01:16  0:00:14   98k\r 86 7464k    0     0   86 6448k      0  84925  0:01:30  0:01:17  0:00:13 98501\r 87 7464k    0     0   87 6544k      0  85001  0:01:29  0:01:18  0:00:11 98520\r 88 7464k    0     0   88 6624k      0  84922  0:01:30  0:01:19  0:00:11 92637\r 89 7464k    0     0   89 6704k      0  84976  0:01:29  0:01:20  0:00:09 89548\r 91 7464k    0     0   91 6800k      0  85048  0:01:29  0:01:21  0:00:08 88385\r 91 7464k    0     0   91 6864k      0  84555  0:01:30  0:01:23  0:00:07 79223\r 93 7464k    0     0   93 6944k      0  84777  0:01:30  0:01:23  0:00:07 81285\r 93 7464k    0     0   93 7008k      0  84677  0:01:30  0:01:24  0:00:06 80659\r 94 7464k    0     0   94 7072k      0  84402  0:01:30  0:01:25  0:00:05 75170\r 95 7464k    0     0   95 7136k      0  84176  0:01:30  0:01:26  0:00:04 69690\r 96 7464k    0     0   96 7216k      0  84114  0:01:30  0:01:27  0:00:03 76349\r 97 7464k    0     0   97 7296k      0  84182  0:01:30  0:01:28  0:00:02 73938\r 98 7464k    0     0   98 7376k      0  84120  0:01:30  0:01:29  0:00:01 74753\r 99 7464k    0     0   99 7408k      0  83606  0:01:31  0:01:30  0:00:01 69747* We are completely uploaded and fine",
    "\r100 7464k    0     0  100 7464k      0  82982  0:01:32  0:01:32 --:--:-- 63467* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse",
    "< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error",
    "< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store",
    "< Pragma: no-cache",
    "< Content-Length: 258538",
    "< Content-Type: text/html",
    "< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT",
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because Linkedin has a 4mb chunk size limit, as per the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api